# TeamCity vs BuildMaster

Tags: teamcity, buildmaster

Somebody mentioned BuildMaster to me lately as build management environment.

http://inedo.com/buildmaster/features/all-features

Does anybody have any experience with this one.  I would like to know how it stacks against TeamCity ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a developer for BuildMaster, I can say that TeamCity and BuildMaster are different products... the main difference being that TeamCity is a Continuous Integration server (i.e. it will automatically take code from SCM, build it, then put an artifact on an integration server), while BuildMaster is designed to do this and take your builds through various environments (dev, test, production, etc.) while also:

- managing database updates
- providing a mechanism to manage and deploy configuration files (e.g. web.config)
- adding on an optional workflow process (e.g. you can add required approvals before promoting a build) if you desire it
- manage application and artifact dependencies
- etc...

Some people even use TeamCity for CI then let BuildMaster handle deployment of the artifact, DB, and configuration files.

Comment: Thank you for the summary, I been using TeamCity for some time now, seems I need to give BuildMaster a try as well